# Get height from this.props.children in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

How to get height from children, passed as props? i mean:

```js
<div>
  {this.props.children} //get height?
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved:

```js
this.childElement.offsetHeight //gives a height

<div ref={(node) => (this.childElement = node)}>{children}</div>
```